# How to inherit generic props in react + typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript and ReactJS. Say, I created a generic component that has some props.

```js
type Props = {
  as: React.ElementType<any>,
  propOne?: string,
  propTwo?: number
};

function GenericComp({
  as: InnerComp,
  propOne,
  propTwo,
  ...rest
}: Props) {
  return (
    <InnerComp
      propOne={propOne}
      propTwo={propTwo}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}


<GenericComp as={AnotherComp} anotherCompProp={2} />
```

I want to retain the props from another comp as well as the generic comp but I don't know how to achieve that in typescript.